# Getting hold of the response on the client side after file upload request

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, servlets

I am using the typical form based upload file functionality with servlet like in here
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/servlets/servlets-file-uploading.htm

The client side code is

```
<html>
<head>
<title>File Uploading Form</title>
</head>
<body>
<h3>File Upload:</h3>
Select a file to upload: <br />
<form action="UploadServlet" method="post"
                        enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="file" size="50" />
<br />
<input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is that on the server side, I write a json output to the response object (stream). On the client side, it is doing a redirect. Basically , redirecting to a page where it just shows the json output.

On the client side, how can I take control of the respone? I would like to parse the JSON and do something with it but I can't find "the hook" or how to get the output. I am using Javascript and HTML on my client side (and AJAX when possible)

Thank you

Comment: onsubmit ... prevent default or return false

Comment: Use ajax to upload your file.  http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/uploading-files-ajax

Comment: If you have an AJAX handler, let's see it. Otherwise, it seems like you're asking us to do your work. [Learn ajax](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_intro.asp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The ajax function**

```
//url,callback,type,FormData,uploadFunc,downloadFunc
function ajax(a,b,e,d,f,g,c){
 c=new XMLHttpRequest;
 !f||(c.upload.onprogress=f);
 !g||(c.onprogress=g);
 c.onload=b;
 c.open(e||'get',a);
 c.send(d||null)
}
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18309057/2450730
works on all latest browsers including mobile.

**Ready function**

```
function rdy(){
 console.log(this.response)// or JSON.parse(this.response) if json
}
```

**Progress**

```
function progressup(e){
 console.log(e.loaded/e.total)// or (e.loaded/e.total*100|0)+'%' to get the percent
}
```

**Setting up the form**

Assuming your form is the first one, you simply prevent it's default behavior and create a custom function, in this case ajax to send the form.

```
window.onload=function(){
 document.forms[0].onsubmit=function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  ajax('upload.php',rdy,'post',new FormData(this),progressup)
 }
}
```

this is all you need, as you can see the code is short... but it has everything you need.

Note: every type of form is accepted... so you don't have to bother writing extra code to read the form values... this thanks using `new FormData()`

**EDIT**

Also the form itself does not need all those extra attributes.

this is enough....(no method,action,enctype)

```
<form><input type="file" name="file"><input type="submit" value="GO"></form>
```

alternatively add multiple to your file imput to upload multiple files.

```
<input type="file" name="file" multiple>
```

if you have any questions just ask

Comment: Thank you cocco  but I notice that you are calling php function in here. My backend does not have PHP. Only servlet receiving the request

Comment: oh sure ... just change the location. replace upload.php with the correct upload addresss

Comment: anyway if asking about javascript you should also post some javascript code to better understand your problem. i just posted a short and powerfull way to handle uploads with ajax.

Comment: YEs upload Servlet. Well I used the HTML code like what I put above. I just said I have JS code as well (to indicate that if a solution involve JS then I am ok, just point me).. IF I can just replace it with Upload servlet then great!

Comment: try it ... i personally never used java... servlets